# Stream syntax for reading from std::vector (or other sequence)?

Tags: c++, templates, stream

Imagine I have a Variant class which can represent a variety of POD types, plus std::string, and I have a template method `T get_value(const Variant&)` that can extract the underlying types from it.

Assume I have a vector of these, ie. `std::vector<Variant> variants;`, and I want to read several values from it with a convenient syntax, like so:

```
int x;
double y;
std::string z;
// Get elements 0, 1, and 2 as int, double, and string respectively
streamlikeObject >> x >> y >> z;
```

The question is: what is a good way to form the hypothetical `streamlikeObject` in the example? I can imagine creating my own class with an extraction operator but I am just interested as to whether there's something in the std library or maybe Boost which handles this sort of thing.

Or alternatively: how else can this data be extracted with a similar degree of code brevity? Maybe there is a better alternative to the stream syntax.

Comment: How about overloading the global operator, `<template T> streamlikeObject & operator<<(streamlikeOperator & s, T & t)`?

Comment: The issue is that streamlikeObject doesn't exist. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like (**untested**)

```
template <typename Iter>
class Extractor {
    Iter cur;
    Iter const &end;

  public:
    Extractor(Iter const &begin, Iter const &end)
      : cur(begin), end(end) { }

    template <typename T>
    Extractor &operator>>(T &x)
    {
        if (cur == end)
            throw SomeException();
        x = cur->get_value();
        ++cur;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Construct with `Extractor<std::vector<Variant>::const_iterator> streamlikeObject(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Alternatively, if you only want to extract from containers, you may want to parametrize the template on the container type instead of the iterator type to save typing (pardon pun).

Comment: I expect the best thing for me to do is write an adapter that takes a container and wraps one of these Extractors.

Answer (score 1):

So let me make sure I understand this correctly.

You have a std::vector, and it contains arbitrary data. The contents of which are runtime-defined.

And you want to take this runtime-defined object and apply a compile-time sequence on it like this:

```
std::vector<Variant> >> val1 >> val2 >> val3;
```

I suppose your code will just throw if the current value doesn't match the expected type, yes?

You could use some of Boost.IOStream's facilities for this. You would basically be making a new stream type that uses your Variants instead of `char`. And you would need a stream buffer that pulls from a (presumably const) reference to a container of these `Variant` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  float b;
  std::string c;
};

std::istream& operator>>( std::istream &is, const A &a )
{
  is >> a.a;
  is >> a.b;
  is >> a.c;
  return is;
}
```

Comment: "btw take a note that std::string is not a POD" - I thought that was obvious by the way I phrased my question.

Comment: @Kylotan Right, I will edit my answer, but I am not quite sure it is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to create something generic, I'd probably try something with `std::tuple`, allowing usage like this:

```
std::tuple<int, double, std::string> input;
streamLikeObject >> input;
```

(Implementation left as an exercise for the reader.)